# What is a correct mongodb collection structure for full-text search?

Tags: mongodb, full-text-search

I have a simple MongoDB website where dedicated search engine (like elasticsearch) will be an overkill and will add support complexity, so I want to stick with MongoDB 2.6 full text search. As i can see, MongoDB llimits text search index to only `one` field per collection. If I have a `Users` collection with and want to enable full text search for both user name and user description, what is a correct collection structure for this? I can suggest to create a separate `Text` collection where I will keep all text information for my website and use it for search. For example, user will be inserted like this:

```
users.insert({
  name_ref: texts.insert({text: "John Doe", type: USER_NAME}),
  description_ref: texts.insert({text: "This is a test user", type: USER_DESCR}),
});
```

Is it a good solution, or so many inter-collection dependencies will kill MongoDB, and I need to use some other appproach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *As i can see, MongoDB llimits text search index to only one field per collection.*

You got it wrong here. A collection can have only one text **index** per collection.
From the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/#create-text-index):

> A collection can have at most one text index.

The index can in turn contain [multiple](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/create-text-index-on-multiple-fields/#create-a-text-index) fields to be indexed for text search.

You could create the index,

```
db.collection.ensureIndex({"userName":"text","description":"text"});
```

And perform a search for a specific keyword as,

```
db.collection.find({$text:{$search:"keyword"}});
```

Your collection can be self contained, without any references to other collections.

```
{
  userName:"John Doe",
  description:"This is a test user"
}
```

Comment: Thanks for amazing answer and happy new year!